# Create publisher dynamically with conditions

Tags: reactor

I'm just looking for an idea for converting this pseudo code into a reactive style.

```
var records = new ArrayList<>(); 

var query   = new Query();
var results = query.executeQuery();
records.addAll(results.getRecords());

while (results.hasMore()) {
query = new Query(results.offset())
deals = hubspotQuery.executeQuery(Deals.class);
records.addAll(results.getRecords());
}
```

The idea is to collect all records into a Flux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one possible solution.  Maybe there is others, but this one is simple.
This is not real code, but it describe the logic.

`Flux<Records> query = createFluxQuery();
query.expand(record -> (record.hasMore()) ?  createFluxQuery(record.offset) : Flux.empty());`